# How would I go from DNF to a simplified formula with less symbols?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

Here's a DNF:
$$(\neg A_1 \land \neg A_2 \land \neg A_3 ) \lor (A_1 \land \neg A_2 \land \neg A_3 ) \lor (\neg A_1 \land \neg A_2 \land A_3 ) \lor (\neg A_1 \land  A_2 \land \neg A_3 )$$

And the problem states "Find a wff for this DNF in which there are at most 5 connective symbols."

I've spent the past hour distributing & using De Morgan's laws and I'm not really getting anywhere. Is there some obvious process that I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The formula is true when at most one of $A_1, A_2$ and $A_3$ is true (and only then).
2. Hence it is the negation of 'At least two of $A_1, A_2$ and $A_3$ are true'.
3. Write 'at least two of $A_1, A_2$ and $A_3$ are true' with five connectives. There is a very natural way of doing this.
4. Now rewrite what you got above with four connectives.
5. Negate what you got on 4.

Comment: Awesome! I see that instead of simplifying what I had, it seems that you looked at the truth table and translated an observation into logical/sentential language. Is this a common strategy to create concise formulas out of CNF's?

Comment: @Steady Doing the truth table would be one strategy, but I can't be arsed with eight line truth tables at this point in life xD My observation really did come from the original formula. The first bit says "it's true when all are false", the second bit says "it's true when $A_1$ is false", etc.

Answer (score 0):

For reasons of space we shall represent the three entities $A_1,A_2,A_3$ by $a, b, c$, and their negations using the bar notation, $\bar a, \bar b, \bar c$.

$\small{\begin{align}
& 
(\bar a\wedge\bar b\wedge \bar c)\vee(a\wedge\bar b\wedge\bar c)\vee(\bar a\wedge \bar b\wedge c)\vee(\bar a\wedge b\wedge \bar c) 
& \text{as given}
\\ \iff & 
\bigl((\bar a\wedge\bar b\wedge \bar c)\vee(\bar a\wedge\bar b\wedge \bar c)\bigr)\vee(a\wedge\bar b\wedge\bar c)\vee(\bar a\wedge \bar b\wedge c)\vee(\bar a\wedge b\wedge \bar c) 
& \text{idempotent}
\\ \iff & 
\bigl((\bar a\wedge\bar b\wedge \bar c)\vee(a\wedge\bar b\wedge\bar c)\bigr)\vee\bigl((\bar a\wedge\bar b\wedge \bar c)\vee(\bar a\wedge \bar b\wedge c)\vee(\bar a\wedge b\wedge \bar c)\bigr) 
& \text{commute and associate}
\\ \iff & 
(\bar b\wedge \bar c)\vee\bigl((\bar a\wedge\bar b\wedge \bar c)\vee(\bar a\wedge \bar b\wedge c)\vee(\bar a\wedge b\wedge \bar c)\bigr) 
& \text{resolve}
\\ \iff & 
(\bar b\wedge\bar c)\vee\Bigl(\bar a\wedge \bigl((\bar b\wedge \bar c)\vee(\bar b\wedge c)\vee(b\wedge \bar c)\bigr)\Bigr)
& \text{distribute}
\\ \iff & 
(\bar b\wedge\bar c)\vee\Bigl(\bar a\wedge \bigl(\bar b\vee(b\wedge \bar c)\bigr)\Bigr)
& \text{resolve}
\\ \iff & 
(\bar b\wedge\bar c)\vee\bigl(\bar a\wedge (\bar b\vee \bar c)\bigr)
& \text{distribute and absorb}
\\ \iff & 
(\bar b\wedge\bar c)\vee(\bar a\wedge \bar b)\vee(\bar a\wedge \bar c)
& \text{distribute}
\end{align}}$

Comment: Your last step doesn't help getting closer to the goal. You should have stopped at the next-to-last.