# Propositional formula, consisting of $p, q, r$ is true iff only one of them is true

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have some difficulties in building a formula $\phi(p, q, r)$, which is true iff only one of the variables is true.

I suppose that it's reasonably to start trying, using the truth table, but building a formula from it actually seems to be a tough job.

In some point of view, the exact formula should contain the $\oplus$ function - for example, $a_{1} \oplus a_{2} \oplus \ldots \oplus a_{n} $ is true iff formula consists only of an odd number of true variables.

Could somebody give me a clue, how to cope with it?

Comment: 'Exactly one' or just 'one'?

Comment: Exactly one variable.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest formula is obviously, $$ ( p \land \lnot q\land \lnot r) \lor ( \lnot p \land \lnot q\land  r) \lor ( \lnot p \land q\land \lnot r) $$

Maybe there is a more succinct and elegant formula but I can't seem to unearth it.

Comment: My answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/938364/how-would-i-go-from-dnf-to-a-simplified-formula-with-less-symbols/938388#938388) provides ways to simplify the statement.

Answer (score 3):

As you observe, $p\oplus q\oplus r$ is true when only one of the variables is true, or when all three are true. Therefore, $(p\oplus q\oplus r) \wedge \neg(p\wedge q\wedge r)$ would fit your needs.